# Ubuntu 14.04.05 + nvidia proprietary + UEFI = taints kernel?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I have well-known issue when after nvidia driver installation - system starts with black screen. If I log into command line, I can check logs:

- in xorg.log I see that "nvidia driver not found"
- in dmesg: "nvidia taints kernel"

What I have tried:

- installed driver from Ubuntu settings (drivers tab)
- installed driver from nvidia package (.run file)
- installed different kernels: 3.x.x and 4.8.15
- compiled custom kernel without signature verification
- disabled verification by mokutil
- installed ubuntu without secure boot (=disabled)
- all this was done on clean ubuntu each time
  And NOTHING works.

But on Ubuntu 16 nvidia works from the box without issues on UEFI.

Problem that I really need Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for work (I use proprietary software which does not support Ubuntu 16).

Any ideas and/or working guide? I believe that it could be solved somehow. I do not need this license/secure issues, it is development system.

Comment: Would it work in 14.04.1 LTS (the first point release instead of the fifth point release)? Can you identify what in 16.04, that makes the proprietary software fail? How does your computer work with the free driver for nvidia, the 'nouveau' driver?

Comment: Yes, in 14.04.1 nvidia also doesn't work. Something with security policy. For development currently I'm trying to get proprietary software running on Ubuntu 16, company said that it possible.